# In Groovy what's the difference between an instance's metaClass and its class's metaClass

Tags: groovy, metaclass

See the following code:

```
class Car implements GroovyInterceptable{}
car=new Car()
Car.metaClass.hello={println "class Car:hello"}
car.metaClass==Car.metaClass
```

the result is:

```
false
```

So my question is: What's the difference between car.metaClass and Car.metaClass? I did some searching, but no result. Could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`car.metaClass` is applicable to the object called `car`. You may modifiy it, but it will not be visible to other `Car` objects

When you modify `Car.metaClass`, that is will be applicable to all objects of `Car.class` (created after this new meta modification)

```
class Car implements GroovyInterceptable{}
car=new Car()

Car.metaClass.accelerate {->println "Factory tested. Safe acceleration"}
car.metaClass.accelerate  {->println "Owner modified : Random acceleration"}

def anotherCar= new Car();
anotherCar.accelerate()
car.accelerate()
```

Output

```
 Factory tested. Safe acceleration
 Owner modified : Random acceleration
```